# Detecting last row of a group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using row_number() to determine the last row of a query by creating descending order and checking if I am on position 1.

```
row | value
----+-------
  3 | false
  2 | false
  1 | true
```

Do you have any idea how to apply the same technique to determine the last row of every group?

The expected result should be like this:

```
uid | row | value
----+-----+-------
  1 |   3 | false
  1 |   2 | false
  1 |   1 | true
  2 |   4 | false
  2 |   3 | false
  2 |   2 | false
  2 |   1 | true
  3 |   2 | false
  3 |   1 | true
```

Or do you know any better way to detect last rows in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`PARTITION BY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html) as part of your `OVER()`:

```
select uid,something,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY something desc) as row
from
  someTable
```

`PARTITION BY` causes whatever window function you're using (such as `ROW_NUMBER()`) to operate complete separately on each partition that is defined - so `ROW_NUMBER` restarts number, `MAX` would find the maximum value for rows within the partition, etc.

Answer (score 4):

To actually determine the *last row* per group (or overall) without an additional subquery, you can use the window function [**`lead()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html). This would work for the less trivial case of ascending order as well:

```sql
SELECT uid, something
     , row_number() OVER w AS row
     , lead(true, 1, false) OVER w AS value
FROM  tbl
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY something DESC);
```

`lead()` has the rarely used feature of a third parameter providing a default, when no "next" row is found in the group. This way you can return a constant `true` for rows with a "next" row and substitute `false` if there is none.

I am also using the `WINDOW` clause, which is just a notational convenience so I don't have to spell out the window definition twice.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, exactly what I needed, you've been a valuable contributor over the years! ❤️